# MediaStore not finding AVI files

Tags: android

I'm trying to find all video files on my device by

```
    String[] proj =
        { 
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE 
        };


    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor videocursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,proj, null, null, null);
```

and it finds mp4 and 3gs files ok, but it does not see any AVI files that I also have and that are found by other video players.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Check which filetypes are accepted by your device, if its not accepted, then it won't be rendered as content.

Comment: but they are found by other video players...

Comment: On your particular device? This is kind of device specific.

Comment: yes, on my nexus s, android 2.3 :)

Answer (score 0):

As can be noted here: **AVI** is not supported in the default supported file types.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html